# In-class initialization of std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have this snippet of C++ code that doesn't compile under g++-4.9.1 (I used the command "g++ -c --std=c++11 map.cc")

```
#include <map>
#include <cstdint>
class A {
  std::map<uint8_t, uint8_t> b = std::map<uint8_t, uint8_t>();
};
```

I get the following error when compiling:

```
map.cc:5:52: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
   std::map<uint8_t, uint8_t> b = std::map<uint8_t, uint8_t>();
                                                    ^
map.cc:5:52: error: declaration of ‘std::map<unsigned char, unsigned char> A::uint8_t’ [-fpermissive]
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/stdint.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/cstdint:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/char_traits.h:380,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/array:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:63,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/map:61,
                 from map.cc:1:
/usr/include/stdint.h:48:24: error: changes meaning of ‘uint8_t’ from ‘typedef unsigned char uint8_t’ [-fpermissive]
 typedef unsigned char  uint8_t;
                        ^
map.cc:5:59: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
   std::map<uint8_t, uint8_t> b = std::map<uint8_t, uint8_t>();
                                                           ^
map.cc:5:43: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 4)
   std::map<uint8_t, uint8_t> b = std::map<uint8_t, uint8_t>();
                                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/map:61:0,
                 from map.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:96:11: error: provided for ‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::map’
     class map
           ^
```

However, if I replace uint8_t with int, it compiles fine.

Comment: This seems to be a GCC problem.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to compile under clang++ (Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu2). I should probably search the g++ bug reports.

Comment: Note that as you have it, the in-class initialization is kind of pointless, since you're just doing default initialization, which will happen without any help from you.

Comment: std::map<int, int> b = std::map<int, int>(); is right uint8_t is wrong.This seems to be a GCC problem

Comment: Could you try `std::uint8_t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, if you need a work around, the following works:

```
class A {
   typedef std::map<uint8_t, uint8_t> B;
   B b = B();
};
```

Comment: It is ok, use gcc 4.8

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. There are a few workarounds for my specific problem, like omitting the initialization altogether like Jerry pointed out. Fwiw, it doesn't work with gcc-4.8/g++-4.8 either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with g++ is much larger, whenever you use a template as a class member, you cannot use member initialization if any parameter (except the first one), is a typedef or in another namespace.

```
typedef int I;

template<typename T1, typename T2> struct A {};

struct B {
    A<I,float> a1=A<I,float>(); // works!
    A<float,I> a2=A<float,I>(); // does not compile!
    // This is the same reason the map does not comile, as string is a typedef
};
```